# How can I get object keys from this union type?

Tags: typescript

I am just wondering how can I get keys form this union type.

Value is getting never type.

I want Value to be sno | key | id

```
type Key = { sno: number } | { key: number } | { id: number };
type Value = keyof Key;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing (or rather, abusing) conditional types, we get:

```
type Key = { sno: number } | { key: number } | { id: number };

type Value = Key extends infer T ? T extends T ? keyof T : never : never;
```

You can read a little more about this behavior [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) (distributive conditional types).

Before we do that though, we use `Key extends infer T` to put `Key` into a naked generic type.